# Send HTTP REQUEST (Authenticate request)

Tags: api, https, request

It is done via iContact Api - but I am not clear on that part: send HTTP request.

I saw an example:

```
Example HTTP Header
Accept: text/xml Note: Values for this are text/xml or application/json
Content-Type: text/xml Note: Values for this are text/xml or application/json
Api-Version: 2.0
Api-AppId: 4eOFlFJabcdenVoljgPv9av59C54alz4
Api-Username: myusername
API-Password: my_password
```

I am sorry for the stupid question and it is my first time to attempt api.

Anyone could lend me a help in how to code to authenticate the https request?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they have examples for the entire API here:

http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/code-library

You can download all the examples from this link:

http://developer.icontact.com/documentation/code-library-zip-file

In the examples zip, the util.php file contains a function (callResource()) that performs the request and sends the authentication headers.

The examples zip also contains a config.php file that must be edited to contain your specific username, passsword and appId.

Comment: thank you for your help. But it does not have the example for sending the https request. i want to authenticate the request before I can start using api.

Comment: @Josephine The authentication is done using HTTP headers.  The util.php file creates the request with the appropriate headers.  You must edit the config.php file and set your username, password and appId.